# How can I install Spotify on a Samsung Galaxy Tab 8.9?

Tags: installation, samsung-galaxy-tab-8.9, spotify

Spotify's installation page forwards me to the Play Store, but the app is not available for my Galaxy Tab 8.9 in the store. Is there any another way install the app?

(It's a European Galaxy Tab with data service, but the app is not blocked based on region since I can install it on my phone without issues.)

Comment: @Matthew Read You did a mistake in closing this question in my opinion, since the problem is not about the region of the market. I can for instance install easily Spotify to my Huawei Ideos X5 -phone in the same market where my tablet is. The problem is in that the Android is recognizing my tablet as not phone so it limits similarly softwares in all markets. Mobile broadband works in my tablet but I cannot call with it. I know that the thing is different in US where Samsung brought slightly different device.

Comment: See also: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/18777/how-to-circumvent-the-market-compatibility-check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get Spotify working by the following method provided by the official suuport:

> Hello there,
>
> Try directing the browser on your tab to the following page -
>   https://www.spotify.com/download/previews/ - and then downloading the
>   preview version of Spotify on Android from there.
>
> This might get it up and running on your device. Please let me know
>   how you get on. Kind Regards,
>
> David
>
> Spotify Customer Service

Answer (score 2):

I contacted Spotify's customer service. Their answer

> Hi Sami,
>
> Thanks for your email, I am sorry to hear you are experiencing
>   problems installing Spotify.
>
> At present Spotify is not compatible with European Samsung Galaxy Tab
>   8.9.
>
> If you have any other queries, please feel free to contact us and
>   we'll be glad to help.
>
> Many Thanks.
>
> Best wishes,
>
> Oggy
>
> Spotify Customer Service

So not supported.
I demanded them to mail me when they get the support.
I will post here when I receive the possible mail.

Answer (score 1):

Try this: Go into your settings and allow apps from external sources. Then download the Spotify apk from here to your tablet, and run it. No guarantees it will work, but if it doesn't, it's not going to break anything.

Edit: It won't create the link for some reason, so here's the URL:

`www.spotify.com/wp-content/uploads/android/0.4.04/SpotifyAndroid.apk`

Another option is to find the apk on your phone, copy it to your tablet, and run that. It looks like it's just a single apk for both tablet and phone.

Comment: And what assurances does anyone have that that's not a trojan horse or some other sort of malware? Almost every malware infection on Android has come from people turning on the ability to add apps from external sources and downloading apps from dodgy sites.

Comment: Hm. Well, none, I guess. Hadn't thought about that. I found it [here](http://www.spotify-forum.com/viewtopic.php?f=46&t=2028). I'll see if I can find a more official apk download.

Comment: @AlEverett There we go, found the apk on the Spotify site, so I'm fairly certain it's not a Trojan ;) Edited my answer to use that link instead.

Comment: The app is now in my Tablet. However, since the device is not a phone, it did not accept my facebook username and password. I asked new password from the spotify staff. I will inform if starts to work.

Comment: @Masi Why would not being a phone cause it to not accept your FB login?

Comment: I am using 2-step verification system on Facebook. I have only Facebook login details. It seems that Spotify tablet app has not taken that into account.

Comment: @Masi Oh, okay. Interesting, I didn't even realize Facebook could do 2-step verification. So the app seems to run fine and everything? I wasn't sure if it would display correctly, given the unusual screen size.

Comment: I turned off the login approvals. The same problem now with real facebook password: Invalid username/password. It seems that the application just do not work with Android tablet.

Comment: That doesn't make much sense. There shouldn't be any difference, no matter where you log in from.