# Is there a way to spoof the phone model that shows up on app ratings/comments on Google Play?

Tags: google-play-store

When a user enters a review comment for an application their phone model/version listed below it. Is there a way to spoof or otherwise change that information?

Answer (score 5):

I believe you'd do this the same way you download apps available for other devices, by editing the build.prop file on your device (requires root).  See my answer [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/16611/1465) for more info on that.