# Installing Android apps from Samsung store to non Samsung Android device like htc phone

Tags: samsung, htc, side-loading, alternative-markets

I have a htc phone, I want to install few apps from Samsung market.

But users of htc can not download apps from Samsung Market, Samsung Market is only available to Samsung devices.

Does anyone know how to install applications from Samsung store to HTC mobiles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've successfully modified the build.prop on my Samsung Vibrant to mimic that of the i9000, allowing me to get i9000 apps from the Samsung app store.  So something similar might work for you.  See [How can I modify the phone model in build.prop to get unsupported apps?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/16610/1465)

Comment: Don't understand. I paid for an app from the Samsung market but the app has no Samsung specific functionality, it's also available in the Google play store. I'm not paying again for an app I already own, short of just copying the files off my tablet (via adb, the display stopped working) what am I supposed to do? I can't even find the Samsung Market!

Comment: @Michael You should post a new question with details specific to your situation.