# How can I trick or force an app to work on an unsupported device?

Tags: applications, android-mini-pc

I recently purchased an iMito MX1 mini-pc. I was disappointed to find that Hulu Plus is not fully supported on my device. I am able to download the app just fine, but I get an in-app error message that tells me that I am able to browse videos through the app, but video playback is not supported.

I have root access and was hoping that [editing the build.prop file](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/5078/is-there-a-way-to-trick-the-android-market-into-thinking-im-using-a-different-d) would trick the app into thinking that my device was supported, but no luck.

Is there any other way to force or trick an app into working on an unsupported device?

Comment: Related: [How can I modify the phone model in build.prop to get unsupported apps?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/16610)

Comment: Well, try decompiling the apk, then see if you can alter code which does the checking for video playback capability. Recompile and put it in. (Fyi,This is very difficult)

Answer (score 1):

You can't FORCE it to work. There may be tricks you can play to fake the app into thinking it's on another device, but for the specific app given (video playback), it's almost certainly refusing to playback because it CAN'T.

The hardware on the device is probably something that the devs didn't anticipate, or that the app can tell isn't fast enough to actually work. Even if you find some way to fake it out and make it try, it's only going to crash or play back so slowly that it will be unwatchable.

Answer (score 0):

You could pull the app apart using apktool an then edit the smali, but as mentioned in previous answers here, that would still lead to problems though. Chances are the developers made the app that way because your device was not capable of playback.

If you are really interested in trying to edit the app's smali, have at it:
https://code.google.com/p/android-apktool/

Answer (score -3):

What you are doing is not recommended. There is a reason why app developers limit installation to select devices. Namely:

1. Android Version
2. Processor Architecture/GPU
3. Chipset/Board/RAM
4. Screen Size/Density/Resolution

This is to ensure good, consistent, and fast user experience as much as possible.

Comment: I can't find the solution in this answer.

Comment: Since the website for Lucky Patcher advertises that it is designed to "bypass premium applications license verification", I am removing it from this answer. We'd like to avoid promoting apps that enable piracy as much as possible. I'm leaving the rest of your answer, though, as it does seem like useful information. If you think this warrants additional community discussion, feel free to post a new question on [meta].